# C# Use Regex to Backspace/Delete?

Tags: c#, regex

I was wondering if it's possible to use regex (or some other tool) to add a backspace in a string

For example if I had a string:

"This test {{replacement}}."

Can I replace {{replacement}} so the final product will be:

"This test."

Comment: If you think about it, this is the same as deleting a space before the replacement, so just search for the replacement that has a preceding space. You can't put really put a backspace in as backspace won't remove a character but you can remove the space.

Comment: `"\b"`  represents a backspace but it will be stored with the string.

Comment: Do you mean removing the particular substring from string?

Comment: Please, share your code so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
Regex regx = new Regex(@" \{{(.*?)\}}");
string input = "This test {{replacement}}.";
var result = regx.Replace(input, "");
```

Working example:[Demo](https://rextester.com/XCO61347)